# C language: remove the last element of a vector

Tags: c, vector

I'm trying to remove the last element of a vector. Returns 0 if the vector is empty, or 1 if not. x takes the value of the last element before it is thrown out.

```
int vector_pop(struct vector *v, int *x)
{
    if (v->size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    x = v->data[v->size];
    free(v->data[v->size]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your question. You have not stated any problem to be solved, you have not provided specific circumstances in which a problem occurs, you have not described the behavior observed when a problem occurs, and you have not described the desired behavior. In this case, the likely error is so simple that experienced people can see it, but, when writing question in the future, you should always provide more information. And your questions should ask a question.

Comment: Do you mean C++?

Comment: I would say no this is not `std::vector` its `c`. Although it would be helpful to see the `vector` struct.

Answer (score 1):

Since your vector contains `int`s, you do not `free` its elements individually. A simple option is to drop `free` altogether, and make sure that you reduce size *before* taking the element off the vector:

```
if (v->size == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
v->size--;
*x = v->data[v->size]; // Note the asterisk
return 1;
```

It is important to keep track of both the allocated size and the effective size when implementing your own dynamic vector. `v->size` tells you how many elements are set in your vector now, while `v->allocated_size` should tell you how many elements you could push into the vector without having to reallocate memory in `v->data`.

Comment: why do we reduce size before taking it out ?

Comment: @SLnettoyeur Because when `size` is, say, `5`, the valid items are stored at indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: I don't understand how we can access the last element at

     x = v->data[v->size];

if we have just reduced v->size by 1. It is the before last element no ?

Comment: @SLnettoyeur No, it's the last element. Do the math to see it. Keep in mind that indexing of arrays in C is zero-based.

Comment: Ah I see... it's a bit like trying to get array[length] which doesn't exist

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Right, I missed that one. Thanks!